# Do USB flash drives delete a sector before writing to it?

Tags: forensics, usb

I know that SSDs can't write to a non-empty sector, so must delete it first (and even support TRIM which resets them automatically after deletion). HDDs on the other, write to sectors before reseting them, leaving file slack of the previous data which could be analysed.

How about USB flash drives?

Comment: There is no one correct answer to this question; there will be exceptions. If residual data extraction is a concern, follow the time-honored tradition of 1) wipe the media, hard 2) burn it 3) grind the ashes into a fine powder 4) secret portions of the well-mixed powder in random locations world-wide, protected by attack dogs. The attack dogs are really just for show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All NAND flash needs to erase the block before writing it. But concerning security, you have to understand that you never know which block is written.
SSD and also USB flash drives have internal controllers and remap the actual flash cells. Each flash cell only has a limited amount of writes before it fails. With the typical use of a USB flash drive or ssd (you have some static files and then you have a part of the drive where you constantly write/delete/change the content) specific parts of the flash would fail very soon, destroying your drive.

Because of this, [wear levelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wear_leveling) is used.

This means if you write to sector X on the drive, the controller might write this to the flash cell 1234. You then want to delete the data there and write random bits to sector X. But the controller decides, that flash cell 1234 is more used than average and decides to write the data to flash cell 543 instead.

The original data is still in flash cell 1234! You can't read it using the controller, because it is marked as empty. But if someone disassembles your USB flash drive and reads the content of the flash cells, the data will be there.

Because there are more flash cells than the advertised storage to allow for some to fail, there is no simple way to prevent this. Even if you fill your whole flash drive with random data, there are still flash cells not written to. The way new SSD disks prevent data leakage is that they have a hardware encryption always enabled. Every bit written is encrypted with a key stored in the controller. If you send a "secure erase" command to the ssd, it simply deletes the key for the encryption and all the data turns into garbage.

So never store any secret data unencrypted on flash memory!

Comment: thanks, but with SSDs which use TRIM, don't they reset the sectors automaticaly when deleted? Or am I missunderstanding it?

Comment: That is entirely implementation dependant! With the TRIM command, the OS just tells the SSD this sectors can now be discarded. A write of a bit in a flash cell is actually the following: Read the data in the cell. Modify the data in RAM (the ram of the SSD controller, not the PC) to include the changed bit. Erase cell. Write new data. When a cell is marked discarded, it can be written to without reading first. The SSD controller can also wipe the cells when idle, but is not forced to!

Comment: By "prevent data loss" you actually meant "leakage" or "exposure", correct?

Answer (score 2):

All modern NAND flash memory is written to in blocks.  This is the same whether it is SSD or USB flash drives: NAND flash memory has a particular implementation that requires writing entire blocks.

An erase block typically is a multiple of the read/write sector size.

Comment: Thanks! and is this the same for NOR flash? Edit: just checked wiki, it is!